# M1 to M2 data migration flat catalog differing

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

When migrating data from M1 to M2, can you migrate with flat product data enabled on M1, but disabled on M2?

Comment: it should be fine. Flat tables are generated during reindex. Its based on product tables etc. Flat tables shouldn`t be migrated between databases.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Trying to decipher why our migration is missing a lot of data, and thought that might be the issue. The products have come across missing name, prices, status, image filename etc. Lots of data like the URL, gallery images, stock etc have come over fine. Will look at log file and retry from scratch I think.

Comment: how do You migrade data ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can migrate your products directly from Magento 1 to Magento 2 manually or by using an automated migration tool. Then easily set the flat product data to disable in the back-end of Magento 2.